# Rails handling a list of collection_select

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Pretty new to Ruby, but I'm working on a website for editing information on bus routes for a larger system. The DB has Route separate from it's list of stops, Trips. I'm trying to make the list of stops for each Route easily editable with a list of collection_select forms, where each presents a list of all of the stops to choose from. That was easy with the code below in 
**routes/_form.html.erb**

```
<!-- handles the list of stops -->
      <div class="stops_list" id="stops_list">
      <%= f.label "Stops", :class => 'control-label'%>
        <% params.merge!(:trips => {}) %>
        <% puts params.inspect %>
      <% trips = Trip.where('route_id = ?', @route.id).order('trips.order ASC') %>
        <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
          <%divId = 'stop'+trip[0].to_s %>
          <div class="controls" id= <%= divId %>>
            <%= f.label trip[0].to_s + '.', :class => 'control-label'%>
            <%= collection_select params[:trips], trip[0].to_s, Stop.order('name ASC').all, :id, :name, {:selected => @trips[trip[0]]} %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

And then I update the proper tables in the DB from the routes_controller based on the data in params. I'd also like to be able to add and remove stops. I tried adding a 'remove stop' button, as below,

```
<%= button_to_function 'Remove stop',
            'if(confirm("Really?")) {
            $("#stops_list div").last().remove();
            $.get("/routes/removeLastStop/'+(@route.id.to_s)+'");
            }'%>
```

and it removes the proper collection_select form, but I then have to remove the stop from params. I tried doing an ajax call, as you can see, but then I have a new instance of the routes_controller, and the params I want to change is inaccessible. I'm not sure if I just set up the stops list wrong in the first place, or if there's a quick fix, but can anyone more experienced point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
Here's the entire form; it's pretty simple until you reach the area I've added

```
<%= form_for @route, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :longname, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :longname, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :color, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :color, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :shape, 'Shape (KML file)', :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.file_field :shape, :class => 'file_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :enabled, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.check_box :enabled, :class => 'checkbox' %>
    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- handles the list of stops -->
      <div class="stops_list" id="stops_list">
      <%= f.label "Stops", :class => 'control-label'%>
        <% params.merge!(:trips => {}) %>
        <% puts params.inspect %>
      <% trips = Trip.where('route_id = ?', @route.id).order('trips.order ASC') %>
        <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
          <%divId = 'stop'+trip[0].to_s %>
          <div class="controls" id= <%= divId %>>
            <%= f.label trip[0].to_s + '.', :class => 'control-label'%>
            <%= collection_select params[:trips], trip[0].to_s, Stop.order('name ASC').all, :id, :name, {:selected => @trips[trip[0]]} %>
          </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= button_to_function 'Remove stop',
                'if(confirm("Really?")) {
                $("#stops_list div").last().remove();
                $.get("/routes/removeLastStop/'+(@route.id.to_s)+'");
                }'%>
      </div>


    <!-- adds submit button -->
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                routes_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can add to Route class:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trips
end
```

Firstly i'd like to advise you using decorators, inserting Models in Views is not the best practice.

Secondly you can use **gem 'draper'** and in RouteDecorator class you can add functions for creating something you want to use or display.

Thirdly you'd better use:

```
<div class="controls" id="stop<%= trip[0].to_s %>">
```

Forthly it would be better to use paths in REST-style:

```
/routes/2/stop/remove
/routes/2/stop/add
```

Fifthly can you give code of all form?
Probably we need to refactor it to look better and be easier for understanding.

Comment: the Route model already has_many :trips, and leaving aside readability, I'm not very familiar with the decorator pattern, but it seems more complicated than the functionality I'm implementing. My big challenge is editing the `params` hash on a button click, or refactoring so that I don't have to.

Comment: So why not to use 
@route.trips instread of Trip.Where?

As i understand your situation:
You remove the last stop using ajax, that's good. You want to filter params - you can do it in private method of controller:
     def route_params
          params.require(:route).permit()#here list all params you need.
       end

As another variant you can use a ActiveModel for Form. It can give you validation, filtering of params and in controller you will check the validity of it.
If form is valid - you can update, if not - show all your errors.

Comment: I don't need to filter the params; I already do. The problem is that I need to remove an entry from the params hash when I remove the last stop from the view, so that the data in params[trips] matches the stops that the user sees. The ajax call isn't working, as I loose access to params when I make the call.